# Holo Everywhere and Sliding Menu

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere, slidingmenu

Well, i have question and i just cant find answer on the internet i spent last couple hours trying to figure out how to implement Holoevrywhere and Sliding menu library in the application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the sample projects of [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) as well as the sample project of [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere). Then combine both.

You need a `git` client (e.g. *Tortoise Git*) for getting a copy of the sources.